# convert time to 100th / 10th of a second resolution

Tags: sql, postgresql

The pattern `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` gets time to seconds resolution.

```
select to_char('2017/02/20 08:23:58.267'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
=> 2017-02-20 08:23:58
```

What patterns would get to 10th of a second and 100th of a second resolutions?

```
100th second resolution => 2017-02-20 08:23:58.27
10th second resolution => 2017-02-20 08:23:58.3
```

couldn't figure out from documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: You can just `cast` it to `timestamp(2)` or `timestamp(1)`. That *cuts* the precision automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/RFQD6294)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT '2017/02/20 08:23:58.267'::timestamp as t1
)    
SELECT to_char(t1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
       to_char(t1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS MS') millisecond, 
       to_char(t1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS US') microsecond       
FROM cte
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

You can use `date_part('microseconds', t1)` and and `date_part('seconds', t1)` with some math to round the desire value.

Answer (score 2):

`'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS'` would give '2017-02-20 08:23:58.270'.  You could just truncate that string by one or two characters.  Or, for accurate rounding, you could do a separate conversion using the pattern `'SS.MS'`, convert that string to a float, round it, convert it back to a string, and append that to the result of `to_char(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI.')`

If it's an option, it seems like it would be easier to just go with three decimal places...